# C# replace chars between set of chars

Tags: c#

if I have:

```
string newMangerName = "RandomName";

string manager = "CN=Kylie Seany,OU=Test,OU=Users"
```

So the CN name value will be different for every manager,

I want to replace the CN name value with newManger

e.g

```
string newManager = manager.replace("afterCN=", replace(newManagerName);
```

Comment: Could use a regular expression, but before that, wanted some additional info if possible. Is there a particular reason the formatting is all in a single string like that, couldn't be read as XML, or your own class?

Comment: @ForeverZer0 It's ActiveDirectory's formatting.

Comment: OK, gotcha. Regex is probably way to go then. I see there is already answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use RegEx:

```
var src = "CN=Kylie Seany,OU=Test,OU=Users";
var res = Regex.Replace(src, "(?<=CN\\=)(.*?)(?=,|$)", "test");
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

`(?<=CN\=)` is a lookbehind requiring that the previous characters were CN=

`(?=,|$)` is a lookahead requiring that the next character is , or the end of the string.

`(.*?)` is a non-greedy match-all.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, if format is fixed you can easily use [Indexof](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_String_IndexOf_System_String_System_StringComparison_) and [Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_) string functions:

```
string newManagerName = "Some Random Name";
string manager = "CN=Kylie Seany,OU=Test,OU=Users";

int index = manager.IndexOf(",OU=");

string newManager = "CN=" + newManagerName + manager.Substring(index);
Console.WriteLine(newManager);
```